# Revoke answer acceptance to ask unrelated or loosely-related follow-up question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, accepted-answer

I've been noticing a trend recently, that plays out as follows:

1. **User A** asks a simple, straightforward question relating to a larger, more complicated project they are working on.
2. **User B** gives a complete, correct, and helpful answer to the question.
3. **User A** accepts **User B**'s answer.
4. Later, **User A** notices a new problem in their project.
5. **User A** un-accepts **User B**'s answer and asks a follow-up question in the answer's comments.
6. Repeat steps 2 - 6

This usually leads to long strings of comments on a single, correct answer to the original question, that get progressively further off topic, while the original answer is not marked as accepted.

On the one hand, this is obviously slightly annoying for User B since he/she has spent a good amount of time helping User A solve their problems, and loses out on a few rep points, but the larger problem is that there are an increasing number of straightforward questions with good complete answers that never get accepted, and have long comment threads talking about how "Now X isn't working", which a newcomer to the discussion might mistake for meaning the original issue is unresolved.

Comment: duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: Yes, I hate this too. What is your question?